# Calculating and adding new rows by dividing rows within a specific condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe as the following:

| DATE | Industry | Statistics | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | Agriculture | Employment | 500 |
| 2022-01-01 | Agriculture | Unemployment | 200 |
| 2022-01-01 | Agriculture | Vacancies | 100 |
| 2022-01-01 | Construction | Employment | 800 |
| 2022-01-01 | Construction | Unemployment | 400 |
| 2022-01-01 | Construction | Vacancies | 100 |

I want to add new rows under Statistics called "UV.rate" which should be calculated by Unemployment divided by Vacancies sorted by DATE, then Industry

I tried this code, but it is not working.

```
    newdf <- bind_rows(
      df,  
      df %>% 
        summarise(VALUE = VALUE[Statistics == "Unemployment"] / VALUE[Statistics == "Vacancies"], 
                  Statistics = "UV.rate")
    ) %>%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slightly shorter alternative is to reshape long to wide to long.

```r
df %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = Statistics, values_from = VALUE) %>%
    mutate(UV.rate = Unemployment / Vacancies) %>%
    pivot_longer(-c(DATE, Industry), names_to = "Statistics", values_to = "VALUE")
## A tibble: 8 x 4
#  DATE       Industry     Statistics   VALUE
#  <chr>      <chr>        <chr>        <dbl>
#1 2022-01-01 Agriculture  Employment     500
#2 2022-01-01 Agriculture  Unemployment   200
#3 2022-01-01 Agriculture  Vacancies      100
#4 2022-01-01 Agriculture  UV.rate          2
#5 2022-01-01 Construction Employment     800
#6 2022-01-01 Construction Unemployment   400
#7 2022-01-01 Construction Vacancies      100
#8 2022-01-01 Construction UV.rate          4
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed `group_by`

```
bind_rows(
  df,  
  df %>% 
    group_by(DATE, Industry) %>%
    summarise(VALUE = VALUE[Statistics == "Unemployment"] / VALUE[Statistics == "Vacancies"], 
              Statistics = "UV.rate")
)

  DATE       Industry     VALUE Statistics  
  <chr>      <chr>        <dbl> <chr>       
1 2022-01-01 Agriculture      2 UV.rate     
2 2022-01-01 Agriculture    500 Employment  
3 2022-01-01 Agriculture    200 Unemployment
4 2022-01-01 Agriculture    100 Vacancies   
5 2022-01-01 Construction     4 UV.rate     
6 2022-01-01 Construction   800 Employment  
7 2022-01-01 Construction   400 Unemployment
8 2022-01-01 Construction   100 Vacancies
```